# Any directories I create have permission 777

Tags: permissions, mkdir, umask

Anytime I create a directory (with `mkdir`, or if `git` creates it, etc) it's given these permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 username usergroup            2 Apr  6 20:36  test/
```

I'd rather have permissions of `755`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 username usergroup            2 Apr  6 20:36  test/
```

When I check `umask` I get `0022`, which I believe should result in files with `755` permissions. I also checked `/etc/login.defs` which shows that my `UMASK` is set to `022`.

Any idea what's going on?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Where is this directory located? In an NTFS partition or an SMB share or something?

Comment: It's on an NFS. I just checked, the problem doesn't occur on the local EXT drive.

Comment: Then maybe the actual filesystem that's being exported over NFS is doing this.